# Binomial Distribution crossword puzzle

Tags: probability

A crossword puzzle is published in the newspaper each day of a week, except Sunday. A man is able to complete on average 8 out of 10 of the crossword puzzles. Find the probability that, in a given period of 4 weeks, he completes 4 or less crossword puzzles in each of the four weeks.

My answer:

X - B(24, 0.8)

P(X≤ 4) = binomcdf (24, 0.8, 4) = 0.000001  (using graphic calculator)

The correct answer is 0.0142.  I am not sure what has been done incorrectly.Help is needed. Thank you.

Comment: You need to compute the probability that he completes at most $4$ crossword puzzles in *each week*, not at most $4$ over the entire four weeks.

Comment: I got it now. It should be X - B(6, 0.8) , then P(X ≤ 4) = binomcdf (6, 0.8, 4) = 0.34464 (probability in a week) , therefore 4 weeks shall be $ (0.34464)^4 = 0.0142 $.